# Bold second item of a selectOneMenu

Tags: java, css, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I've got a selectOneMenu which has all cities of a state. I've made a sql to bring capital in first place, but i'd like to bold it to make it more visible to who is using it. Is there a way to bold it or to do something else to make more visible just the second option?

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{someBean.cityId}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{addressBean.stateList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML `<option>` element as generated by `<f:selectItems>` allows for very little fine-grained styling and the CSS support is browser-dependent. You *could* use the CSS3 `:nth-child` pseudoselector. E.g.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{someBean.cityId}" styleClass="cities">
    <f:selectItems value="#{addressBean.stateList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```css
.cities option:nth-child(2) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But this doesn't work in all browsers. Only Firefox eats that, but MSIE and Chrome not. The latter two doesn't do that because they don't allow setting `font-weight` on the option. But they allows you to change the (background) color by `color` or `background-color`:

```
.cities option:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

This works in all CSS3 capable browsers so far (i.e. thus not in MSIE8 or older).

If you want best cross browser compatibility, you'd need to replace the `<select>` by an `<ul><li>` along with a good bunch of CSS/JS code to make it look like a real dropdown. You could then style the `<li>` elements individually. You could throw in some jQuery plugin or to look for a 3rd JSF component library. PrimeFaces 3.0 has a [`<p:selectOneMenu>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) which does exactly that.

Comment: The styleClass on selectOneMenu and it did not work, got any other idea? It can be a different background color or something like this. Thx

Comment: As said, the HTML `<option>` element allows for very little fine-grained styling. Bold works in Firefox only (and even then only when you open the dropdown and check the list item!). You could use `background-color` instead, but that produces different results in browsers. MSIE shows it already in the `<select>`, but FF and Chrome not, it only shows it inside the opened dropdown list. If you want full control over styling, you really have to use an `<ul><li>` which mimics an dropdown. See also the PrimeFaces component link.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work with bold but with different colors. I was checking to see how would it look, and i saw that i really want the second child, and tried "second-child" instead of "first-child" but no success.

Comment: Use the CSS3 `:nth-child()` pseudoselector instead. `.cities option:nth-child(2)`. Again, you're dependent on browser support. It doesn't work in for example IE8 and older, only IE9 and newer. I updated the answer.