# How to color individual items of tr:selectOneChoice?

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-1.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bold second item of a selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717022/bold-second-item-of-a-selectonemenu)

Is it possible to paint/color item in the select items drop down?

My Code:

```
<tr:selectOneChoice value="#{bean.entity}> 
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.entities}" />
</tr:selectOneChoice>
```

backing bean:

```
public List<SelectItem> getEntities() {
   List<SelectItem> entities = new ArrayList();
   SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
   item.setValue("value");
   item.setLabel("label");
   entities.add(item);
}
```

I want to add styleclass to the item. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, usually that's not possible and its rendering depends on browser.
If absolutely necessary, you will have have to create a `<div>` and style it to look like dropdown.